# Transform uibutton change height

Tags: objective-c, transform, frame

After transform  uibutton change  height and setFrame does not work. After this. Help me. My code here:

```
NSLog(@"BEFORE_Frame_height = %f", nameBgBtn.frame.size.height);
NSLog(@"BEFORE_Bound_height = %f", nameBgBtn.bounds.size.height);
nameBgBtn.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(rndValue));
CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(nameBgBtn.frame.origin.x,nameBgBtn.frame.origin.y, nameBgBtn.bounds.size.width, nameBgBtn.bounds.size.height);

[nameBgBtn setFrame: newFrame];
[nameBgBtn setBounds:newFrame];
NSLog(@"After_Frame_height = %f", nameBgBtn.frame.size.height);
NSLog(@"After_Bount_height = %f", nameBgBtn.bounds.size.height);
```

My logger:

```
2013-03-07 15:30:23.887   BEFORE_Frame_height =  46.000000
2013-03-07 15:30:23.888   BEFORE_Bound_height =  46.000000
2013-03-07 15:30:23.888   After_Frame_height  =  49.887489
2013-03-07 15:30:23.888   After_Bound_height  =  46.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

There is difference between `frame` and `bounds`, especially when you are changing the `transform`. In your code you are mixing both and the result is not what you expect.

1. You apply some rotation by setting `transform`.
2. You create rectangle with `origin` of the **new frame** and size of `bounds`. The `bounds` didn't change using `transform`.
3. You set this rect to `frame`. The view does not move (the same `origin`), but it gets scaled down, because you are changing outer dimensions.
4. You set the same rect to `bounds`. I'm not sure what happens if you set `bounds.origin` to non-zero value, but the contents of button may be translated. Also it scales the button up, because `bounds.size` is set to the same as before.

To be clear:

- `bounds` = rect in **inner coordinate system**, usually `origin` of zero (except for scroll views) and with desired size.
- `frame` = rect in **superview (outer) coordinate system**, with any `origin` and the `size` **may be the same as `bounds.size`**. The `frame` is calculation of `center`, `bounds` and `transform`.
- `transform` = how `bounds` are transformed to make `frame`. Mapping of inner to outer coordinates.

If you have button with size `{50, 80}` and you apply 90° rotation, the `bounds.size` will be **the same** `{50, 80}`, also `center` will not change, but `frame` reflects the new transformed size `{80, 50}`.

I hope it's clear now.

---

**Update:** Here is an image showing difference between `frame` and `bounds`.
[image: Frame vs. bounds]
Dark square is `bounds`, light square is `frame`. On the first image, they have the same size. On the second image, the view has rotated `transform`.

Comment: i've transformed to 4 degree. I want the height of the button has not changed. what should I do?

Comment: If you want the height to be the same, don't change `frame`. In fact, you don't need to change anything except the `transform`. The `frame` will get bigger automatically. See updated answer with image.

Comment: i think you are did not understand me? My UIButton after transform change its original height. Why, i don't know!

Comment: Did you set _only_ `transform` or did you change `frame`/`bounds` also? How did you know the height is changed? By eye or by logging `frame.size.height` or `bounds.size.height`?

Comment: by eye.My button has a background image. This button is on the other button. also, transfromed.